# Make text grow uni-directionally on calling set('text', 'some value')

Tags: fabricjs

Currently, whenever I set the text of a **fabric.Text** object dynamically, using the set('text', 'some random text') function, the width seems to grow bi-directionally i.e from both the left and right side.
Is there any way to make it grow from either the left or right side only.
I have achieved this by explicitly calculating the **top_left_x, top_left_y, top_right_x, top_right_y** and using some arithmetic logic for the same.

But what is there any internal fabricJS property (or something similar) by which this can be achieved.

For ex: In the *Kitchensink* demo, if you add a new Text object and modify the text in the lower-right text area, you will see that the text grows from the right while its left side remains fixed. This is exactly what I wish to achieve.

Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because the default origin point is the center of object. So you need set the "originX" to "left". As you can see in the [Kintchensink source file](http://fabricjs.com/js/kitchensink.js):

```
document.getElementById('add-text').onclick = function() {
  var textSample = new fabric.Text(text.slice(0, getRandomInt(0, text.length)), {
    left: getRandomInt(350, 400),
    top: getRandomInt(350, 400),
    fontFamily: 'helvetica',
    angle: getRandomInt(-10, 10),
    fill: '#' + getRandomColor(),
    scaleX: 0.5,
    scaleY: 0.5,
    fontWeight: '',
    originX: 'left',
    hasRotatingPoint: true
  });
  canvas.add(textSample);
  updateComplexity();
};
```